Android Data Binding Type Mismatch in RecyclerView with MVVM
I'm developing an Android notes app using Kotlin and MVVM architecture. I'm facing a persistent type mismatch error when using data binding in my RecyclerView, even though the code seems correct.
Error Message
Assignment type mismatch: actual type is 'com.im_oregano007.noteit.Notes.Note', but 'Notes.Note?' was expected.
Code Snippets:

Note Entity (Complete File)

package com.im_oregano007.noteit.Notes

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.util.Date

@Entity(tableName = "notes")
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int,
    var title : String,
    var value : String,
    val date: Date)


RecyclerView Item Layout:

<layout ...>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="n"
            type="com.im_oregano007.noteit.Notes.Note" /> 
    </data>
    ...
</layout>


Adapter:

class NotesAdapter(...) : RecyclerView.Adapter<...> {
    ...
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cNote = noteList[position]
        holder.binding.n = cNote
        ...
    }
}


ViewModel:

class MainViewModel(val notesRepository: NotesRepository) : ViewModel() {
    var notesLiveData : LiveData<List<Note>> = notesRepository.getAllNotes()
}


MainActivity (Observer):

mainViewModel.notesLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
    if (notesAdapter != null){
        notesAdapter!!.updatedNotes(it)
    } else {
        notesAdapter = NotesAdapter(this,it)
        setUpRecyclerV()
    }
})

What I've Tried:

I've ensured that the variable in the layout file is non-nullable (Note).
I've removed unnecessary null checks in my binding adapters.
I've double-checked that the adapter is set on the RecyclerView correctly.
I've verified that the noteList contains non-null Note objects.

Despite these efforts, the type mismatch error persists. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

There are 2 problems
Problem 1: MainActivity (Observer):
variable this can be null. you need to check it.
Problem 2: in onBindViewHolder
replace holder.binding.n = cNote
with cNote?.let{holder.binding.n = it}

didn't worked, the problem as i could find by more research is , problem with the package structure, if i'm keeping the notes related file in the seperate package and using data binding(working if not using data binding) it is not working and if i move these files to the main package then it's working anyways...
